# Ошибка подключения библиотеки в AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sdk

возникла ошибка при подключении библиотеки в IDE AndroidStudio. Данный вопрос есть на просторах интернета но все они 2011-2019 годов и поэтому не помогают.
Вот код build.gradle(app) в котором не хочет подключаться `implementation 'com.androidx.support:design:32.0.0'`

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myitschool"
    minSdk 16
    targetSdk 31
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

// Add this line
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

dependencies {

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.4')
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

implementation 'com.androidx.support:design:32.0.0'
}
```

Приведу еще build.gradle(название)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
        google()  // Google's Maven repository

    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'

    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.0' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
allprojects {

    repositories {
        // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
        google()  // Google's Maven repository
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }

    }
}
```

И соответственно вот код ошибок, после сборки. Ошибки именно из-за подключения библиотек!

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 8 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
  The project declares repositories, effectively ignoring the repositories you have declared in the settings.
  You can figure out how project repositories are declared by configuring your build to fail on project repositories.
  See https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sub:fail_build_on_project_repositories for details.
   > Could not find com.androidx.support:design:32.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/androidx/support/design/32.0.0/design-32.0.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/androidx/support/design/32.0.0/design-32.0.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
  The project declares repositories, effectively ignoring the repositories you have declared in the settings.
  You can figure out how project repositories are declared by configuring your build to fail on project repositories.
  See https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sub:fail_build_on_project_repositories for details.
   > Could not find com.androidx.support:design:32.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/androidx/support/design/32.0.0/design-32.0.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/androidx/support/design/32.0.0/design-32.0.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

3: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
  The project declares repositories, effectively ignoring the repositories you have declared in the settings.
  You can figure out how project repositories are declared by configuring your build to fail on project repositories.
  See https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sub:fail_build_on_project_repositories for details.
   > Could not find com.androidx.support:design:32.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/androidx/support/design/32.0.0/design-32.0.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/androidx/support/design/32.0.0/design-32.0.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

4: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
  The project declares repositories, effectively ignoring the repositories you have declared in the settings.
  You can figure out how project repositories are declared by configuring your build to fail on project repositories.
  See https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sub:fail_build_on_project_repositories for details.
   > Could not find com.androidx.support:design:32.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/androidx/support/design/32.0.0/design-32.0.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/androidx/support/design/32.0.0/design-32.0.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

5: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
  The project declares repositories, effectively ignoring the repositories you have declared in the settings.
  You can figure out how project repositories are declared by configuring your build to fail on project repositories.
  See https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sub:fail_build_on_project_repositories for details.
   > Could not find com.androidx.support:design:32.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/androidx/support/design/32.0.0/design-32.0.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/androidx/support/design/32.0.0/design-32.0.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

6: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
  The project declares repositories, effectively ignoring the repositories you have declared in the settings.
  You can figure out how project repositories are declared by configuring your build to fail on project repositories.
  See https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sub:fail_build_on_project_repositories for details.
   > Could not find com.androidx.support:design:32.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/androidx/support/design/32.0.0/design-32.0.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/androidx/support/design/32.0.0/design-32.0.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

7: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:desugarDebugFileDependencies'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
  The project declares repositories, effectively ignoring the repositories you have declared in the settings.
  You can figure out how project repositories are declared by configuring your build to fail on project repositories.
  See https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sub:fail_build_on_project_repositories for details.
   > Could not find com.androidx.support:design:32.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/androidx/support/design/32.0.0/design-32.0.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/androidx/support/design/32.0.0/design-32.0.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

8: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
  The project declares repositories, effectively ignoring the repositories you have declared in the settings.
  You can figure out how project repositories are declared by configuring your build to fail on project repositories.
  See https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sub:fail_build_on_project_repositories for details.
   > Could not find com.androidx.support:design:32.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/androidx/support/design/32.0.0/design-32.0.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/androidx/support/design/32.0.0/design-32.0.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 8s
21 actionable tasks: 8 executed, 13 up-to-date
```

Comment: Версии такой нет. А если есть, то в ней найти не может какие-то разрешения

Comment: Если я укажу версию ниже, выйдет ошибка в самом редакторе, без компиляции

Comment: Если библиотека 32, то и сдк, наверное, надо как минимум 32.

Comment: Тоже не вариант, т.к. в проекте sdk стоит 29 android Q. + ко всему заморочка идет с androidX.support и android.support. Непонятно, какой ставить

Comment: Замените design библиотеку на `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:<version>'`, версию, например, можно взять 1.4.0. design библиотека уже давно устарела

Comment: Спасибо, я это и искал, потому что на оф сайте библиотек указано, что надо использовать более новые, а какие это более новые непонятно. Можете написать это в ответе, чтобы закрыть вопрос?